# In Eclipse where to add an external library for a Contextlistener?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

In Eclipse Oxygen I have a Java Web app project (Project Facets "*Dynamic Web Module*", "*Java*" and "*JavaScript*"). This project implements a `ServletContextListener` which in turn accesses the database.

In the ContextListener I want to use an external library given as a jar file (`json-20200518.jar` from the `org.json` project). In the ContextListener I want to call

```
import org.json.*
```

**Where/how do I add the library to the Eclipse project?**

---

#### Notes

1. In Eclipse's Project tree I can see  *Web App Libraries* and in the Build Path Dialog is additionally an entry *EAR Libraries*, but I don't know which entry is the correct one for the ContextListener and how then to add the JAR.
2. The project is not a Maven project. We add external jars directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i solved this was:

1. I checked where the *existing* external jars were located. (In  *Web App Libraries*, which translated to a certain directory in the file system.)
2. Add the new library jar to this directory.
3. Hit refresh in the Project Explore on *Web App Libraries*. (**Important!**)

Now Eclipse knows about the new `org.json` library and you can use in imports.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I got some jar files in E:\repository

In Eclipse, I choose "Window" -> "Preferences" -> search for "plat" and choose "Target Platform" -> select the current project and click "Edit" -> "Add" E:\repository

It is all set now, I'm able to use those jar files in my project

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible option to add jars in eclipse project, in case if we are not using maven in our application.

I) Project-> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jars

II) Create folder in project with name libs and put all your jar files there, and then right click -> and select option "Add to build path".

But it is always better to use any build tool, so it will do all housekeeping for you.

Answer (score 0):

Copy it into the project's `WEB-INF/lib` folder, so that it's there at development time and deployed at runtime.